# Detection screen disconnection in linux

Tags: screen, x11, detection

We have a nasty little problem.  In short we can detect if a screen is connect when x11 boots (we do this by looking at the log - Xorg.0.log), but we are having trouble detect when are screen is disconnected while the machine is running (ie post x11 boot)

Any one have any ideas?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xrandr prints the status of a screen ("connected", "disabled", "disconnected").

**Edit**:
But at least on my binary-nvidia-driver machine it always reports "connected".  I suspect a better driver (e.g. intel, radeon) could work though.

Comment: Cheers

by the looks of it this functionality is only support from version 1.2 of this command.  At present we are locked into ver 1.1, this is based on the fact that we are using fedora core 3.

But cheers and thanks for the help